# ZIO, Getting started, pure functional downloader

Tags: scala, functional-programming, zio

I have a simple program that is more or less a downloader. It collect one or many configurable resources (via a custom protocol), aggregate and write them in on place.

This program seems simple but the code is still complex and mix functional and procedural code (from my Java background). I would like to simplify it and move to an fully functional one. I am reading about *ZIO* and the whole picture start to build in my head.

However, after having read the getting started and the overview I still have some questions.

The main flow may be like :

```
for {
  config    <- Configuration.parse(args)
  resources <- Downloaders.download(config)
  _         <- Writer.write(resources)
} yield ()
```

1. I guess the configuration that contains static values but also one http client will be put into ZIO `Environment`.
2. The downloaders may be effects built from a future and may use the ZIO `bracket` to close the connection. I guess that I can aggregate the results with `fold`. But I don't know how to create and execute many downloaders.

   **Edited a)** Since `Future` are note pure, how can I model a effect that will run asynchronously (I plan to use Play Standalone WS Client) ?

   **Edited b)** I should create one downloader per target, the request will be assigned to them. But how should I implement that in my code ? Should I create a `ZIO[Configuration, Throwable, List[Downloader]]` and then, later, execute all of them via `collectAllPar` ?
3. I have no idea on how to write the aggregation on disk.

I would like to use this project to promote ZIO internaly. So I would like to use the best options and cleanest approach. Can someone give me some tips on how to implement those effects and structure my code ?
**Edited:** Should I build my system on the ZIO components or build a set of functions and wrap them into the ZIO effects ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't think you understood how ZIOs (or suspended side effects in general) work. The ZIO does not care if you want to run it in parallel or not. It depends what you do with it (how you execute it) that defines if it is executed in parallel or not, because it is pure.

Comment: Then yes, I don't understand. Because there is an explicit support for concurrency in ZIO. How can I fork one effect to many and join them back to one if I don't "tell" it in the code. For what I understand it can always execute my flow in one thread but It won't parallelize it If I don't tell it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very specific which means that unfortunately it won't attract high-quality answers.

I will still try to answer some of the points.

- `Future`s are not pure. If possible, avoid them.
- Your donwloader will be a function `Request => ZIO[R, E, Response]`. To make them run in parallel, use `ZIO.collectAllPar` or `ZIO.zip`. The result is a `ZIO[R, E, List[A]]` or a `ZIP[R, E, TupleX[...]]`, which you can store in `resources` in your for-comprehension.
- Writing data to a file can be done with Scala's `new PrintWriter(new File("hello.txt"))` wrapped into, you guessed it, a `ZIO.bracket`.

For more insights into program design with ZIO I would suggest reading [Beautiful, Simple, Testable Functional Effects for Scala](http://degoes.net/articles/zio-environment) from De Goes himself.

Also, of course, refer to the documentation found on [ZIO's website](https://zio.dev/docs/overview/overview_index).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Mu question is vague because it is still unclear on how to get started. I have a some more question from your answer. I am going to edit my question to add them.